# Is it impossible to create neumorphic soft UI on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Now, I saw so many design about Neumorphic Soft UI and I have no idea about that for implement on iOS ( swift 4 ). I saw so many tutorial about this but for iOS13+ and SwiftUI only not for swift4 that i want.

If anyone know please help me.

[image]

Comment: Not finding any tutorials on it doesn't mean it's impossible, but why are you still using Swift 4?

Comment: @Sweeper Because my company still use xcode 10 for build and testing so if we moved we'll take so many effort for that.

Comment: https://github.com/mumty13/MHSoftUI

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to achieve this the Swift 4 code is no different to Swift 5. So you should just be able to use the code from whatever non-SwiftUI tutorials you've found.

The basics of replicating this though is you need two shadows, one that sits above and to the left of the view, and another that sits below and to the right.

```
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = false

let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15
let shadowRadius: CGFloat = 2

let darkShadow = CALayer()
darkShadow.frame = bounds
darkShadow.backgroundColor = backgroundColor?.cgColor
darkShadow.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.87, green: 0.89, blue: 0.93, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
darkShadow.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
darkShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowRadius, height: shadowRadius)
darkShadow.shadowOpacity = 1
darkShadow.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
yourView.layer.insertSublayer(darkShadow, at: 0)

let lightShadow = CALayer()
lightShadow.frame = bounds
lightShadow.backgroundColor = backgroundColor?.cgColor
lightShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
lightShadow.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
lightShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -shadowRadius, height: -shadowRadius)
lightShadow.shadowOpacity = 1
lightShadow.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
yourView.layer.insertSublayer(lightShadow, at: 0)
```

There are 3 main things in the above code that are required otherwise the shadows will not render.

1. The view must set `masksToBounds` to `false`—since the shadows will be outside of the bounds
2. You must assign a `backgroundColor` to the layers
3. You must set a `shadowOpacity` since the default is `0.0`—setting `1.0` produces the closest results to your image

You likely want to have the shadows flip when the view is pressed, for that you simply need to switch the `shadowOffset`s of both the sublayers.

```
lightShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowRadius, height: shadowRadius)
darkShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -shadowRadius, height: -shadowRadius)
```

and when the user stops pressing reset them

```
lightShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -shadowRadius, height: -shadowRadius)
darkShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowRadius, height: shadowRadius)
```

For a `UIControl` you will likely be doing the above in the `didSet` of an `isHighlighted` override.

Comment: Using this solution in a UIButton is hiding the button image, so you should add a new image button programmatically after adding the shadow effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pod for adding Neumorphic Soft UI to a UIButton in UIKit such as on:
https://github.com/PallavAg/SoftButton